# Can't access Javascript object

Tags: javascript, arrays, ionic-framework, javascript-objects

I am creating an app in ionic. In that I need to store a value of an object into another variable; the name of the array of objects is `username`.

This is `username[0]` :

```
Object {username: "user1"}
```

Here I want to store the value of `username` into another `$scope` variable. So I did as follows:

```
$scope.username=$scope.username[0].username;
```

But, it returned error. Why? and how to solve it.

Comment: And what is the error?

Comment: I wrote array of objects. Is there any explanation about why did I get a negative vote?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, if `username` was an array in the first place in your code, and you write:

```
$scope.username=$scope.username[0].username;
```

So you are overwriting your existing `username` array with an `object`, then the next time you will call `$scope.username[0].username` it will fail and throw an error :`Can't read property username of undefined`because `username[0]` is `undefined` here.

So you need to use different variables in the scope to refer `users` and `username`.

Comment: It says in the question that the _array of objects_ is named `username`, not the object. Although there's no code to confirm whether that actually is the case...

Comment: it's an array of object. The console output  Object {username: "user1"}  displayed after I console.log($scope.username[0]);

Comment: @camoflage It makes sense now, you are overwriting the `array` with an `object` if you write: `$scope.username=$scope.username[0].username;`, take a look at my edit.

Comment: @Roope Yes indeed it's an `array` but he's overwriting it with an `object` and it wasn't clear from the beginning.

Comment: nope.. didn't work...I think i need some other techniques.

Comment: @camoflage how ` it didn't work?` what did you tried?

Comment: @camoflage Don't you think the error message would be relevant information? You say "it returned error" in the question. Anyway, it's somewhat hard to try to help when there's almost no code or other information at all.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var obj = {username: "user1"};

$scope.username = obj.username;
```

Answer (score -1):

You have an **object** but you are trying to access it as an **array** with `[0]` and thus will return you `undefined`

You can either access your object with the dot notation

```
obj.username
```

or with the brackets notation

```
obj["username"]
```

```js
let username = {
  username: "user1"
};

console.log(username.username);
console.log(username['username']);
```

Comment: It says "the array of objects" in the question.

Comment: @Roope I think that OP is wrong and actually has an object

Comment: it is an array of object.  The console output Object {username: "user1"} displayed after I console.log($scope.username[0]);